# User management in CherryPy

Tags: python, authentication, security, cherrypy

I'm going to develop a web application based on CherryPy. It will be an app where public users can register and will login afterwards - the usual stuff. Other frameworks like Rails and Django contain sophisticated code regarding security: encrypted and salted passwords, prevention of session hijacking, ... Is there something like this already available for CherryPy? I found only very simple solutions so far!?

Answer (score 1):

Does this help? - [CherryPy Digest and Basic Authentication Tutorial (Internet Archive copy)](https://web.archive.org/web/20101222021019/http://old.blog.jimhoskins.com/?p=5)

I have a cherypy application which uses the ldap module to interact with ldap auth system, but seems your app needs to manage the usr/passwds within itself. You could probably put the registered user/passwords encrypted in a database table and tweak the scheme outlined in the above blog.

Answer (score 1):

I used this Authentication example including the fixes in the comments.

http://tools.cherrypy.org/wiki/AuthenticationAndAccessRestrictions

Here's how I encrypt

```
import Crypto.Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import hashlib

# salt size in bytes
SALT_SIZE = 16

# number of iterations in the key generation
NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS = 20

# the size multiple required for AES
AES_MULTIPLE = 16


__all__ = ['Encryption']

class Encryption(object):
    def generate_key(self, password, salt, iterations):
        assert iterations > 0    
        key = password + salt    
        for i in range(iterations):
            key = hashlib.sha256(key).digest()  

    return key

    def pad_text(self, text, multiple):
        extra_bytes = len(text) % multiple    
        padding_size = multiple - extra_bytes    
        padding = chr(padding_size) * padding_size    
        padded_text = text + padding

        return padded_text

    def unpad_text(self, padded_text):
        padding_size = padded_text[-1]    
        text = padded_text[:-padding_size]

        return text


    def encrypt(self, plaintext, password):
        salt = Crypto.Random.get_random_bytes(SALT_SIZE)    
        key = Encryption.generate_key(self, password, salt, NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS)    
        cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)    
        padded_plaintext = Encryption.pad_text(self, plaintext, AES_MULTIPLE)    
        ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(padded_plaintext)    
        ciphertext_with_salt = salt + ciphertext

        return ciphertext_with_salt
```

Then call the encrypt function

```
encryptedPassword = Encryption.encrypt(self, Password, bytes(cherrypy.request.app.config['Encryption']['Password'], 'UTF-8'))
```

Hope this helps!

Andrew